# 110v 220v do it work?

Tags: voltage, resistance

i bought hookah heater from amazon. this product link is [http://www.amazon.com/Proctor-Silex-34101-Proctor-Silex-Burner/dp/B000690WNU/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1413662717&sr=8-2&keywords=hookah+heater](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000690WNU)

this product work on 110 v. But in my country all products works 220 volt. if i practice to work this product, what it will do ?

thanks..

Comment: It will explode in a massive fireball killing you, your whole family, your neighbours, and your neighbour's dog. The fire will spread to the next town, killing millions. **DO NOT DO IT**

Comment: Majenko is right, it probably will melt down and all the magic smoke will come out.

Comment: I think maybe magic smoke is what he's looking for .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will deliver 4000W of power instead 1000W.

But it won't do this for long. The heating element will melt and arc in a matter of minutes, the voltage will short circuit to protective earth and hopefully your circuit breaker or fuse will blow.